# How do I make Visual Studio display "auto" types

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2015, auto

So, when I use auto keyword in VS2015 with something simple, like this:
[image]

As you can see, it shows the variable's type, but, when I try something a bit more complex (or defined in another file?), it freaks out and gives me some not-so-useful information: [image]

Although VS is still able to determine top's type:
[image]

So, I wonder if there is a way to make this wonderful IDE show those complex/defined somewhere else types?

Comment: Looks like your top is an object of template class type as well as the member of one?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/inline-hints-c-please-do-not-use-ctrl-twice-shortc/1696647) thread, Microsoft changed the shortcut keys.
The relevant settings are here
[image]

Comment: My keyboard shortcut for this recently changed to `Alt`+`F1`.

Answer (score 1):

At our company, we use the Visual Assist extension (not free unfortunately, but understandably). It can find the class for the auto keyword when you choose "Goto implementation" (Alt+G).

Answer (score 1):

> vs2022 now supports pressing ctrl twice to display the actual type represented by auto.

If you are using **Visual Assist** on Visual Studio 2022 `double ctrl` (mentioned by [@Kargath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72298856/10133085))  will not work.

Press `Alt + F1` to display the hidden types.